# XQuartz keeps opening after I quit it, regardless if Rstudio is open or not

Tags: xquartz

Lately, I cannot keep XQuartz closed. It will automatically open when I launch RStudio, but now it will open immediately after I quit it. Over and over again, it will always reopen. I finally uninstalled XQuartz even though it is needed.

I'm running the latest versions of MacOS, R, Rstudio, and Xquartz. I've even uninstalled and reinstalled things multiple times.

Additionally, I'm not convinced it's even working probably when I'm running things that need X11.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since you posted the question and I had this issue now. Just post my solution here for reference.
https://github.com/rstudio/packrat/issues/308#issuecomment-909070754

`rm *.Rproj`

`rm -rf .Rproj.user`

Comment: Sadly, this did not work for me.